# SQL select values into multiple variables from different rows in same table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that is structured like this:

```
|ROWID |COUNTRY|PRICE|
|1     |US     |15|
|1     |UK     |10|
|1     |EU     |12|
```

I need to select the values from multiple rows into variables for use throughout a stored procedure, doing something like this:

```
DECLARE @USprice int,@UKprice int
SELECT @USprice = T.Price FROM Table T WHERE T.Country = 'US'
SELECT @UKprice = T.Price FROM Table T WHERE T.Country = 'UK'
```

The question is what's the fastest way to run this select? In reality I need to get about a dozen rows so am concerned about performance.

Would it be better to do this:

```
DECLARE @USprice int,@UKprice int
SELECT @USprice = CASE WHEN T.Country = 'US' THEN T.Price ELSE @USprice END
,@UKprice = CASE WHEN T.Country = 'UK' THEN T.Price ELSE @UKprice END
FROM Table T WHERE T.Country IN ('US','UK')
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL.)

Comment: Looks like T-SQL (MS-SQL-Server)

Comment: Both of the approaches will work,but you will be getting last values assigned to variables,if price returns more than one value.You can join this tables,instead of assigning variables

Comment: Also you can use Space and enter as well for formatting,no need of html ..http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

I will not go with the first approach which require individual table hit for each variable which is not efficient

Here is the correct way to achieve the goal using your *second approach*. You need to add `Min/Max` aggregate on top of your `case` statement.

```
DECLARE @USprice INT,
        @UKprice INT
SELECT @USprice = Max(CASE WHEN T.Country = 'US' THEN T.Price ELSE NULL END),
       @UKprice = Max(CASE WHEN T.Country = 'UK' THEN T.Price ELSE NULL END)
FROM   Table T
WHERE  T.Country IN ( 'US', 'UK' )
```

Considering the `T.Country` column is not duplicated

Comment: For the OP's benefit ; Not putting `ELSE` in there creates an *implicit* `ELSE NULL`.  And then `NULL` is always treated "last" in `MAX()`.

Comment: @MatBailie - added to the solution